# How to export html page to word document with pictures

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Currently, I've a UI that will help me download the displayed HTML page into a word doc with a click of a button. But if the displayed page has few pictures then those are not visible in the word document. What could be done for this?

Comment: Pictures may not be shown if they are coming from different origin.

Answer (score 0):

- https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
- [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

First convert it to canvas, then convert to PDF